# Trouble with Jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I'm trying to make this Jsfiddle to demonstrate an issue but I can not get it to function properly, can anybody advise?

This is the [live demo site](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/) that I am recreating a Jsfiddle for.

Here is my progress on the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yw1hgd8/). As you can see the thumbnails in my fiddle are not expanding and help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
/*
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7243260-2']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
*/
```

```css
    /* default.css */
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
    
    html { height: 100%; }
    
    *,
    *:after,
    *:before {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    /* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    
    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    
    .clearfix {
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
        background: #f9f9f9;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #333;
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    a {
     color: #555;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .container {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .container > header {
     width: 90%;
     max-width: 1240px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
     padding: 0 30px 50px 30px;
    }
    
    .container > header {
     padding: 60px 30px 50px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container > header h1 {
     font-size: 34px;
     line-height: 38px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-weight: 700;
     color: #333;
    }
    
    .container > header h1 span {
     display: block;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .main > p {
     text-align: center;
     padding: 50px 20px;
    }
    
    /* Header Style */
    .codrops-top {
     line-height: 24px;
     font-size: 11px;
     background: #fff;
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
     text-transform: uppercase;
     z-index: 9999;
     position: relative;
     box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .codrops-top a {
     padding: 0px 10px;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     color: #333;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .codrops-top a:hover {
     background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
     color: #000;
    }
    
    .codrops-top span.right {
     float: right;
    }
    
    .codrops-top span.right a {
     float: left;
     display: block;
    }
    
    
    /* Component.css */
    
    .og-grid {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 20px 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    .og-grid li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 10px 5px 0 5px;
     vertical-align: top;
     height: 250px;
    }
    
    .og-grid li > a,
    .og-grid li > a img {
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     display: block;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .og-grid li.og-expanded > a::after {
     top: auto;
     border: solid transparent;
     content: " ";
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     pointer-events: none;
     border-bottom-color: #ddd;
     border-width: 15px;
     left: 50%;
     margin: -20px 0 0 -15px;
    }
    
    .og-expander {
     position: absolute;
     background: #ddd;
     top: auto;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: 10px;
     text-align: left;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .og-expander-inner {
     padding: 50px 30px;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    .og-close {
     position: absolute;
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     top: 20px;
     right: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .og-close::before,
    .og-close::after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     top: 50%;
     height: 1px;
     background: #888;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .og-close::after {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    
    .og-close:hover::before,
    .og-close:hover::after {
     background: #333;
    }
    
    .og-fullimg,
    .og-details {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .og-details {
     padding: 0 40px 0 20px;
    }
    
    .og-fullimg {
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .og-fullimg img {
     display: inline-block;
     max-height: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .og-details h3 {
     font-weight: 300;
     font-size: 52px;
     padding: 40px 0 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .og-details p {
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 22px;
     color: #999;
    }
    
    .og-details a {
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: #333;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     border: 3px solid #333;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 30px 0 0;
     outline: none;
    }
    
    .og-details a::before {
     content: '\2192';
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .og-details a:hover {
     border-color: #999;
     color: #999;
    }
    
    .og-loading {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #ddd;
     box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ccc;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
     -webkit-animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
     -moz-animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
     animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes loader {
     0% { background: #ddd; }
     33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
     66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes loader {
     0% { background: #ddd; }
     33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
     66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
    }
    
    @keyframes loader {
     0% { background: #ddd; }
     33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
     66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    
     .og-expander h3 { font-size: 32px; }
     .og-expander p { font-size: 13px; }
     .og-expander a { font-size: 12px; }
    
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    
     .og-fullimg { display: none; }
     .og-details { float: none; width: 100%; }
     
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container"> 
   <!--/ Codrops top bar -->
   <header class="clearfix">
    <h1>Thumbnail Grid <span>with Expanding Preview</span></h1> 
   </header>
   <div class="main">
    <ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
     <li>
      <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
       <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
       <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/3.jpg" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
       <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="img03"/>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/4.jpg" data-title="Sea lettuce" data-description="Bell pepper eggplant water spinach bell pepper radicchio kale artichoke earthnut pea beet greens carrot celtuce peanut radish mustard jícama tomato bamboo shoot quandong.">
       <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="img04"/>
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <p>Filler text by <a href="http://veggieipsum.com/">Veggie Ipsum</a></p>
   </div>
  </div><!-- /container -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/grid.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    Grid.init();
   });
  </script>
  <script src="//tympanus.net/codrops/adpacks/demoad.js"></script>
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "cannot get it to function properly".

Comment: browser developer tool console says `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://fiddle.jshell.net/0yw1hgd8/show/js/grid.js”.` and therefore `ReferenceError: Grid is not defined` - this is because you have `<script src="js/grid.js"></script>` ... why would jsfiddle know about **your** server?

Comment: @JaromandaX That was the problem, it works now

Comment: @ScottMarcus "As you can see the thumbnails in my fiddle are not expanding" what I meat was in the live demo the images expanded when clicked, in my fiddle they didnt and I needed them to.

Comment: include jQuery library to your Jsfiddle and code from scripts you are refer to (like grid.js)

Comment: @IP_ Yes, I didnt know how to fully to that but I think I might know now, thanks

Comment: On script field "JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS)". Click dropdown and select libs and frameworks you need. Copy-paste code (or related parts) from other js files of your app.